# Bad Request when sending request to WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf

When I use the methods below to send an xml request to an asmx service, it works fine, the only difference is is that the content type is `application/soap+xml`.  I am getting the error: 400 Bad Request.  Here is the method I am using below to send the request via HTTP Post to the WCF Service:

```
private static void SendRequest(string request)
{
    var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://urltoservice.svc");
    req.ContentType = "text/xml";
    req.Method = "POST";

    using (var stm = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {

            stmw.Write(request);
        }
    }


    byte[] myData;
    using (var webResponse = req.GetResponse())
    {

        var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        myData = ReadFully(responseStream);
    }

    // Do whatever you need with the response
    string responseString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myData);
}
```

It seems to throw it at the line:  `var webResponse = req.GetResponse()`

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Whoever did it, care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of service that you are trying to call. Is it REST WCF service or SOAP WCF Service?

You can monitor your request using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see how your request looks when it works and when it doesnt.

Also enable [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service to know why you get a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Neither, its just a plain old HTTP POST

Comment: I am referring to the Service(*.svc)?

Comment: Yeah, I was told it is neither, it is just an HTTP POST.

Comment: You said it works when sending request to .asmx right? In that case i assume the .svc should be a SOAP request? Do you have access to the WCF Service?

Comment: I got it. I needed to append the method name to the URI.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this works, if someone can explain it it would be great.  I needed to append the method name to URI in order for it to work, for example,

`http://urltoservice.svc/MethodToCall`

Comment: The above service is hosted via the REST mechanism and hence you need to specify which resource needs to be acecssed by adding the method name to the end

Comment: I'm still slightly confused especially when someone is telling me it is not REST.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: REST is based on HTTP protocol(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)